# ImportError: cannot import name 'CTGANSynthesizer' from 'ctgan' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ctgan/__init__.py)

Tags: python, generative-adversarial-network, data-generation

I am working on synthetic data generation from GAN but facing some issues with the `CTGANSynthesizer`. Here is the code sample:

```
from ctgan import CTGANSynthesizer
ctgan = CTGANSynthesizer() 
ctgan.fit(data)
```

I am getting an error as shown in the screenshot: [Error of given script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjLXH.jpg).
I am trying to generate some Bengali text data from a Bengali text dataset using this GAN.

Comment: Did you come from studyng the book MLE on AWS?

Answer (score 2):

See the update-log, the model is now named differently:

```
## v0.6.0 - 2022-10-07

This release renames the models in CTGAN.
 `CTGANSynthesizer` is now called `CTGAN`
and `TVAESynthesizer` is now called `TVAE`.
```